# Navigation Back to another View Controller instead of from which it appeared

Tags: ios, swift

is it possible to change the previous view controllers of a `UINavigationController`?

Suppose I have three view controllers (A, B, C) which are embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Tapping a button in A pushes to B and tapping a button in B will pushes to C. Now, if the user taps on the back button of C, I want redirect the user directly to A instead of B.

Comment: show your code first to ask question.

Comment: Use unwind segue read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44513291/retrieving-stack-of-viewcontrollers-when-segueing-programatically/44513322#44513322

Comment: @Gagan_iOS.There is no need of Code.it so simple problem and which can explain by example.so why you need code to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove B from your navigation controller's `viewControllers` array in C's `viewDidAppear` method.

```
var didRemoveB = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !didRemoveB {
        navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(atIndex: 1) //assuming B's index is 1
        didRemoveB = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let arrViewControllers: [Any]? = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
    for controller: Any in arrViewControllers! {
        if (controller is cVC) {
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller as! UIViewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is -

```
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewControllerA, animated: true)
```

For more info, read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller).

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios) to learn how to combine it with the back button.

Comment: This also worked. To use this one i need to change back button to custom back button or change back button action. because if user swap to go back it will show second View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in many way,
First you can handle when your ViewController B is disappear and change stack of viewControllers in navigationController

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()){
      self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers // your viewControllers stack
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

or pop to root:

```
self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated()
```

or pop view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.:

```
self.navigationController.popToViewController(:animated:)
```